# Java. Скачивание файла по ссылке через временный файл

Tags: java

Всем привет!
Есть задача: скачать файл по ссылке во временную папку, потом переместить этот файл в заданную папку.

Вот код рабочего метода:

```
public static Path downloadFile(String urlString, Path downloadDirectory) throws IOException {
    // implement this method
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    String filename = urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, urlString.lastIndexOf('.'));
    String suffix = urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf('.'));
    InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(filename,suffix);
    Files.copy(inputStream, tempFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    Path target = Paths.get(downloadDirectory + "/" + filename + suffix);
    Files.move(tempFile, target);

    return target;
}
```

Вопрос: почему, если убрать `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING` из метода `Files.copy` вылетает исключение `FileAlreadyExistsException`, если я пытаюсь скопировать файл из потока в только что созданный, а значит пустой временный файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> в только что созданный, а значит пустой временный файл

Только что созданный файл действительно является пустым, но для метода [`Files.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) неважно, пустой файл или нет, важно лишь существует файл или нет. Из документации к методу:

> By default, the copy fails if the target file already exists

что можно перевести как

> По умолчанию операция копирования завершается неудачно если файл существует